# Dynamic Linq searching multiple columns of multiple types including nullable types

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I need select my columns dynamically and I do not know the types of the columns ahead of time. I've got a string and I want to search all the columns if they contain that string, converting non-string into string for the comparison.

```
string format = "Convert.ToString({0}).Contains(@0)";
Model.Where(String.Format(format, columnName), searchString);
```

It breaks on nullable types, but that should be okay. I can use HasValue and Value and then convert to string. To do that I need to check that the type is Nullable<> with typeof.  So I wrote a big nasty string to pass to dynamic linq, and it broke on `typeof`  I've tried to write an expression tree but I'm not getting anywhere. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Its about how to operate with DLINQ, it  can help